# Simplify Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

The following Boolean expression is simplified into its minimal number of literals:

$$x'y' + yz +x'yz' \implies x'+yz.$$

How do you logically conclude this using the Boolean Laws?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving an answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
x'y' + yz + x'yz' &=
x'y' (z+z') + (x+x')yz +x'yz' &\mbox{(identity)} \\&=
x' y' z  + x' y' z' + xyz + x'yz + x'yz' &\mbox{(distributivity)} \\&=
x' y' z  + x' y' z' + xyz + x'yz + x'yz  + x'yz' &\mbox{(idempotence)} \\&=
x'(y' z + y' z' + y z + y z') + (x+x')yz &\mbox{(distributivity)} \\&=
x'+yz. &\mbox{(identity)}
\end{align*}
$$